# Magento 2 - What is the happen when run setup:di:complie

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

When I run this command:

> php bin/mangento setup:di:compile

It will throw the Error Exception below:

```
[ErrorException]
  Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper\Interceptor and Magento\Framework\Interc
  eption\Interceptor define the same property ($pluginLocator) in the composition of MyPool\AttrProduct\Controll
  er\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper\InterceptorCus. This might be incompatible, to improve maintaina
  bility consider using accessor methods in traits instead. Class was composed
```

Anybody know what this means and how to fix it?

content of file "InterceptorCus.php"

```
<?php
namespace MyPool\AttrProduct\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper;

/**
 * Interceptor class for @see
 * \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper
 */
class InterceptorCus extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper\Interceptor
{
    use \Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request, \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\StockDataFilter $stockFilter, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Initialization\Helper\ProductLinks $productLinks, \Magento\Backend\Helper\Js $jsHelper, \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\DateTime $dateFilter)
    {
        $this->___init();
        parent::__construct($request, $storeManager, $stockFilter, $productLinks, $jsHelper, $dateFilter);
    }

}
```

Comment: Use the php bin/magento setup:di:compile-multi-tenant , and tells me if the error continues

Comment: Are you sure that you are running this command ?? Caz i can see that there is a wrong syntax! 'mangento' is not right ! It should be magento

Answer (score 0):

This message means that `MyPool\AttrProduct\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper\InterceptorCus` has properties that do the same thing more or less and can be incompatible with one another. 
Try to refactor the class.

If you can share gist link to the class in question we may be able to help more.

UPDATE: The issue is that the class you extend uses the same trait as your class:

```
    use \Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor;
```

Remove the use statement in `MyPool\AttrProduct\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Initialization\Helper\InterceptorCus` and you should be fine

Comment: I updated my question, detail file was shown